# Can I test whether the browser supports the viewport meta tag "interactive-widget" property?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, browser-feature-detection, viewport-meta-tag

In Chrome 108 support was added for [a new viewport meta tag property](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/viewport-resize-behavior), `interactive-widget`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="interactive-widget=resizes-content">
```

Is there a way to test from Javascript whether the browser supports this property, without resorting to user-agent sniffing?

Comment: I assume you could set it to `resizes-content` and then resize and test the height/width of the container to detect if it indeed did the resizes-content

Comment: @mplungjan Oh, yes possibly. However the virtual keyboard might not show up instantly? Which means such a test might take up enough time that the user can notice it and see the keyboard appearing and disappearing. Also you'd need to test multiple options of the `interactive-widget` property so that you can tell whether the browser's default is being overridden (the property was added because browsers were inconsistent.) It would be more ideal if there was a way to detect support directly.

Comment: You will likely have a better chance here https://www.chromium.org/developers/technical-discussion-groups/